# Destroyed component called 'updated' hook

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router, vuex

### Version

- Vue@2.5.16
- Vuex@3.0.1
- VueRouter@3.0.1

### Code

- First my code looked like this

  ```
  export default {
    //...
    updated () {
      //TODO
    }

    destroyed () {
      this.unregisterModule(module.name)
    }
  }
  ```
- **But when the app get other route, this component will call the `updated` once and cause some problems.**
- Now I use the `_isDestroyed` state property to resolve this:

  ```
  updated () {
    if (!this._isDestroyed) {
      //TODO
    }
  }
  ```

### Question

How to understand this logic of hooks?

Comment: Could you create a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (perhaps on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/df4Lnuw6/169))? There's too little code for us to help you.